# Laravel "delete does not exist."

Tags: laravel

Estou com um erro quando eu tento apagar um elemento do meu banco. 
Todas outras ações de inserir ta dando certo. [image: erro].

eu tenho um botão de ação q deveria pagar um exame da minha tabela

[image: tabela]

So que aparece que o método delete não existe.

[image: delete]

esse é meu controller

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A rota ta funcionado corretamento, porque as outras funções do crud ta normal.

Rout:list
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

achei um erro parecido com o meu mas não entendi como deveria aplicar no meu projeto. Estou mexendo com laravel apenas a 1 mês.

Erro parecido: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23985

Comment: Por favor envie o php artisan route:list

Comment: Rout list: add no no post

Comment: o que tem na variável `id`, sei que ela é uma  `collection`, mas poderia por favor colocar o conteúdo dela?

Comment: Oque tem na variável id é o que aparece na tabela da imagem acima em Cod do exame, que seria o id do exame a qual eu quero excluir

Comment: Dica: Nas próximas perguntas envie o código e os erros como texto, e não como imagem, em imagem fica difícil tentar pegar o código para tentar replicar o erro.

Comment: Perdão priemira vez que pergunto na plataforma, mas caso alguem queira fazer algum teste vou disponibilizar o meu gitHub com o projeto-> https://github.com/CarlosEduardo12/Projetos-Web. so precisa adicionar  pasta vendor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o Route Model Binding funcione, ou seja, o modelo em causa e carregado com base no id passado no URL e passado como parâmetro ao método do controlador é necessário que o segmento do URL e nome da variável no método sejam iguais.

No caso na rota você tem `test/{test}` e no método

public function destroy(Test $id)

essa assinatura deveria ser:

public function destroy(Test $test)

Verifique a documentação para [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding)

O action do seu form também está mal penso que deveria ser

```
action=“{{route(‘tests.destroy’, [$e->id])}}”
```

Comment: Usando a mesma assinatura não da erro de método não encontrado, mas aprece: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Veja a minha reposta editada na parte do form

Comment: esse é meu git com o projeto caso tenha disponibilidade para testar https://github.com/CarlosEduardo12/Projetos-Web

Comment: Na action do form o segundo parâmetro é um array você está a passar uma string deveria colocar [$e->id]

Answer (score 0):

No lugar de

`action="{{ route('test.destroy', '$test->id') }}"`

Coloque

`action="{{ route('test.destroy', $e) }}"`

Você está passando a Collection inteira, quando o método delete aceita apenas uma instância da Model

E na assinatura do método no Controller

```
public function destroy(Test $test){ }
```

Comment: fiz essa modificação so com o > e, e com > e->id e nao deu certo. cod com o codigo no meu git -> https://github.com/CarlosEduardo12/Projetos-Web/tree/master/Pratico_3

Answer (score 0):

nao dá pra vc remover pq vc ta passando apenas o id mas nao especifica em qual model ele vai fazer essa operação.

mude isto:

```
public function destroy(Test $id)
{
$id->delete();// como pego o registro correto se nao sei em qual Model buscar pelo ID?
}
```

para isto:

```
public function destroy(Test $id){
 $test = Test::find($id);// pega a registro do Model Test pela ID 
 $test->delete(); // agora vc deleta o registro pq vc acessou ele corretamente.
 session()->flash('mensagem','Exame excluido com sucesso');
 return redirect()->route('test.index'); 
}//desta forma agora deveria funcionar
```

Comment: Trocando para essa forma ele me redireciona para uma pagina :Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. Eu troquei para usar o model Test que é aonde ta o id que eu quero excluir! Imagem com a toca feita-> [img](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/err1-jpg).

Comment: Meu git com o projeto caso tenha disponibilidade para testar https://github.com/CarlosEduardo12/Projetos-Web

Answer (score 0):

Divida respondida!

Resolução: Na action do form o segundo parâmetro é um array você está a passar uma string deveria colocar [$e->id] –obs: estava passando com aspas simples.

credito: @Jorge Costa

Obrigado a todos, todas as observações foram de boa valia!!